# Split data into two columns using CSS

Tags: mysql, css, row

What I wanna create is page that fetches results from my DB and display them into two columns like this using CSS (unless theres a better way)...

```
Row 1 | Row 6
Row 2 | Row 7
Row 3 | Row 8
Row 4 | Row 9
Row 5 | Row 10
```

The second column  should be empty if theres no more than 5 rows.

Comment: Ok well the maximum number of rows is 5, so what if I do a table and using ONE sql query have the first 5 rows in the first column and if theres more than 5 rows it will output the next 5 in the second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if your goal is to have a list that wraps into two columns, there is no standard way to do this in CSS. One method that CSS3 offers (but most browsers don't support) is the `columns` property, but the bad part about this rule (the last time I checked) is that it forces you to choose up front how many columns you want and you can't specify the idea of "max-columns".

But the best workaround I've found is at [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/):

[CSS Swag: Multi-Column Lists](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlists/)

But if you just want multiple columns of data, the best solution is to use HTML tables.

Answer (score 0):

if you had a fixed number of rows for column 1

css:

```
.leftcolumn
{
Float:left;
}
.other
{
display:none;
}
```

html

```
<div class="leftcolumn">
return some rows here
</div>

<div class="<? other ?>">
return more rows here
</div>
```

php or whatever language

```
if 
[select count(*) from table where foo=bar DESC limit 20,0] >5
other = "other"
else
other = "leftcolumn"
```